# h2metrics/constructKnots.m - ERROR

Tags: matlab, function, syntax-error, code-metrics

I'm trying to run the following code:

"https://github.com/h2metrics/h2metrics/blob/master/constructKnots.m"

```
%% constructEmptySplineData
%
% Function constructs an empty splineData struct. Some default parameters
% are being set; others are set to empty arrays.
%
% Default parameters
%   dSpace = 2
%   phiEps = 1e-12
%   a = [1 0 1]
%
% Output
%   splineData
%       The created struct.
%
function [ splineData ] = constructEmptySplineData

splineData = struct('nS', [],...
'nT', [], ...
'nPhi', [], ...
'N', [], ...
'Nt', [], ...
'Nphi', [], ...
'quadDegree', [], ...
'dSpace', 2, ...
'phiEps', 1e-12, ...
'a', [1 0 1], ...
'knotsS', [], ...
'knotsT', [], ...
'knotsPhi', [], ...
'innerKnotsS', [], ...
'innerKnotsT', [], ...
'innerKnotsPhi', [], ...
'periodic', 1, ...
'noInterpolS', [], ...
'interpolS', [], ...
'stepsT', [], ...
'quadData', [], ...
'quadDataTensor', [] );

 end
```

but I obtained the following error(s):

```
  >> Error using constructKnots (line 20)
  Not enough input arguments.

 >> constructKnots(splineData)
 Undefined function or variable 'splineData'
```

Also, I observed SplineData function is created here:

"https://github.com/h2metrics/h2metrics/blob/master/constructEmptySplineData.m".

```
 %% constructKnots
 %
 % Function constructs the knot sequences with the given parameters from
 % splineData. The knot sequences are uniform in space and time, periodic in
 % space and with full multiplicity at the boundary in time.
 %
 % interpolS is set automatically using N and nS.
 %
 % Input
 %   splineData
 %       Contains information about spline degree and number of control
 %       points.
 %
 % Output
 %   splineData
 %       Same as input with knot sequences.
 %
function [ splineData ] = constructKnots( splineData )

if ~isempty(splineData.N) && ~isempty(splineData.nS)
N = splineData.N;
nS = splineData.nS;
% Normalize, domain of definition is [0,2*pi]
splineData.knotsS =  [(-nS):(N+nS)]/N*2*pi; 
splineData.innerKnotsS = splineData.knotsS(nS+1:end-nS);

splineData.noInterpolS = splineData.N;
innerKnotsS = splineData.innerKnotsS;
if mod(splineData.nS, 2) == 0 % See deBoor for reasons for this.
    splineData.interpolS = innerKnotsS(1:end-1)' + ...
                            0.5*diff(innerKnotsS)';
  else
    splineData.interpolS = innerKnotsS(1:end-1)';
 end
 end

if ~isempty(splineData.Nt) && ~isempty(splineData.nT)
Nt = splineData.Nt;
nT = splineData.nT;
splineData.knotsT = [ zeros(1,nT), linspace(0,1,Nt-nT+1), ...
                      ones(1,nT) ];
splineData.innerKnotsT = splineData.knotsT(nT+1:end-nT);
end

if ~isempty(splineData.Nphi) && ~isempty(splineData.nPhi)
Nphi = splineData.Nphi;
nPhi = splineData.nPhi;
% Normalize, domain of definition is [0,2*pi]
splineData.knotsPhi =  [(-nPhi):(Nphi+nPhi)]/Nphi*2*pi; 
splineData.innerKnotsPhi = splineData.knotsPhi(nPhi+1:end-nPhi);
end

end
```

I do not know how to create a connection between those 2 links.

From my point of view it seems to be ok... Could you help me, please to find the bug.

Comment: The code is indeed ok, it's `splineData` that's not. Or more precisely, it's the absence of `splineData` that's causing the error. How do you call the function?

Comment: is there any chance to make it running? thank you!

Comment: Sure you can. I suggest you have a look at the [example](https://github.com/h2metrics/h2metrics/blob/master/example.m). In the beginning it is explained how you can construct `splineData` and what every field means.